# Button OnClick Fired Multiple Times on Mobile Devices

Tags: javascript, ajax, mobile

I have a page that has a menu and a content area. I dynamically load content into this area via ajax.

```
 <div id="content"  style="visibility: visible; overflow: hidden; top: 0px;"></div>
```

The ajax call looks like the following.

```
  $('#content').load('content/contactform.html',function(){ ...some code...}
```

The page that is loaded into the content box is a form that has a Button defined with an onClick method

```
<div>
    <h2>Phone Numbers</h2>
    <div id="form">
    </div>
    <button id="addPhoneBtn"  onclick="alert('click')">Click Me</button>
</div>
```

Normally it would add a new input field to allow the user to enter more phone numbers. But for testing it just prints an alert.

When I now click that button on a mobile device such as an IPad, the event is fired three times. I have read that on touch devices don't have mouse events. They have touch events.

But the strange think is that if I copy that page directly into the content, the onClick event is only fired once. Am I missing something ?

Update: I'm using Iscroll to make the content that is inside the div scrollable.

Comment: Touch Devices do have onclick event's but it will fire three times due to it 'selecting', 'pressing', 'leaving', Im pretty sure that it is like so... for selecting, its when you don't press the button but you 'tap' down on the button which will then select the button

Comment: But why does it work if I place the content directly in the content box ? I'm using Iscroll to make the content box scrollable. Could that be the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I was using **iscroll-4** to achieve the scrolling on touch devices.
Removing this library and switching to the dojo framework, solved this issue.